# Notify AWS Elastic Beanstalk to swap applications only when everything is up

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application deployed on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk made with love and NodeJS (Webpack, ExpressJS).

When I'm deploying it to the production - everything is started - ExpressJS server, setting up connections, fetching initial data - everything takes couple of minutes.

The problem is that the previous production package is already removed because new one was deployed and during this time everything is down (white page under the production domain) and waiting until node finishes his initial jobs.

Is there any sensible solution that can - for example - send some signal to the AWS and tell "hey, I'm done and app is running - now you can swap the old version with me"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "swap environment urls" feature of EB. You can find the details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)